# Why is my type definition rejected as cyclic when declared as a variant, but accepted otherwise?

Tags: types, functional-programming, ocaml, ml, cyclic

I was messing around with using OCaml implementing some of the data structures in Chris Okasaki's Purely Functional Data Structures and came across this type definition:

```
 type tree = Node of int * int * tree list;;
```

I didn't think it needed the tag as it wasn't a union type, so I tried eliminating the tag, however I got the following error:

```
# type tree = int * int * tree list;;
Characters 5-33:
type tree = int * int * tree list;;
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Error: The type abbreviation tree is cyclic
```

Why does this happen with two seemingly equivalent type definitions?

Comment: I know nothing about ocaml, but could it be that without the `Node of` the type in question means "an int, an int, and a tree", which means it has an unknown size? In .NET (the framework I place my allegiance to) this would be known as a "struct". Basically, every tree is two integers + a tree, which, unless you allow for pointers which would allow for null-pointers (or whatever this would be called in ocaml) would have an unknown size?

Comment: A friend of mine just told me that this is caused by ML's attempts to fully expand the second one and merely type check values created by the first one.  Since in the first case the burden is on the programmer to create values that terminate.

Comment: Shouldn't the question be: Why is my type definition accepted when declared as a variant, but rejected as cyclic otherwise?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In ML-like languages, the definition of a recursive type is one where the recursion does not pass through a variant type. This is a pragmatic definition, in the sense that it tends to lead to more useful type checking.

There's nothing intractable about recursive types. You can enable support for recursive types in OCaml with the `-rectypes` flag.

```
$ ocaml -rectypes
        OCaml version 4.02.1

# type tree = int * int * tree list;;
type tree = int * int * tree list
# let x: tree = (3, 3, [(4, 4, [])]);;
val x : tree = (3, 3, [(4, 4, [])])
```

All of the usual strong typing guarantees are present when recursive types are enabled. The main downside is that many unintended programs are accepted. In other words, the presence of a recursive type is often an indication of a programming error.

Answer (score 1):

The first type definition defines new type. When you omit the constructor name, then instead of defining new type you're actually introducing a type abbreviation. And by default type abbreviations are not allowed to be recursive, since usually this is not what you mean.

You can use any type definition syntax that defines new type to create recursive types, not only variants. Records will work also, for example

```
type tree = { node : int * int * tree list }
```

or even better

```
type tree = {
  value : int;
  depth : int;
  children : tree list;
}
```

(note: field names were chosen arbitrary as I don't know their original purpose)

To summarize, sum types are used not only to introduce disjoint sets of types, but for creating new types also, thus:

```
 type t = Constr x
```

introduces type `t`, that can be constructed with constructor `Constr` from values of type `x`.